# SpriteKit - create sprite in Gamescene.sks and reference in another class

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I know I can use the following in GameScene.swift to reference a sprite I created in the level editor:

```
ball = childNode(withName: "ball") as? SKSpriteNode
```

what if I want to reference that ball from a Ball class? Below is what I thought would work. I was wrong. In the level editor I've given the ball the custom class of Ball.

1. I've created a ball sprite in `GameScene.sks` and assigned it the Custom Class of `Ball`:

[image: sprite in GameScene.sks]

2. This is my custom `Ball` class. (You can ignore the contents, because it doesn't work.)

   ```
   class Ball: SKSpriteNode {

     init() {
       let size = CGSize(width: 35, height: 35)
       super.init(texture: nil, color: UIColor.clear, size: size)

     }

     required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
       fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
     }

     func moveBall() {
       self.position = CGPoint(x: 50, y:50)
     }
   }
   ```
3. Then, in `GameScene.swift`, I'd like to use the `Ball` function `moveBall()` I defined.

   ```
   class GameScene: SKScene {
     var ball = Ball()
     override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
       ball.moveBall()
     }  
   }
   ```

Comment: @squarehipp10 I've edited your question because your original code completely conflicts and contradicts with the newly added code causing confusion. If you wish to have people help you then you need to supply feedback to their answers and their comments. Just changing your question to some different code without providing feedback is completely counter intuitive. You need to check out my answer. This is a very simple matter and I've tested it this morning with this exact code and it works.

Comment: @RonMyschuk - first, I greatly appreciate your time and effort. It may be a simple matter to you, but I've been beating my head against a wall trying to figure this out. Second, I felt like the responses did not address my original question so I tried to clarify it. I was trying to ask the exact same question a little differently.

Comment: you are missing the point of my comment. I assume that this is not an easy matter for you, why else would you be asking the question then? But if you don't supply feedback you aren't likely to receive the kind of help that you may need. I happen to know that Fluid, Whirlwind and myself are capable in helping you with this matter, but you need to help us help you

Comment: FYI it is referred to as the "Scene Editor" by Apple https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/Fox/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: Thanks to all. Now that I understand the answer, your answers make much more sense. I wasn't getting that I needed to reference the ball sprite in the Scene Editor from `GameScene.swift` and not my custom class. Every time I've created a custom class in SpriteKit, I used it to create a new sprite. I thought referencing a sprite from the Scene Editor would be much the same.

Comment: glad it worked out for you, and that you understand why it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Edit

If you want to add an custom object to the Scene editor you need to add the following initializer to your custom class.

```
class Ball: SKSpriteNode {

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
  }

  func moveBall() {
    self.position = CGPoint(x: 50, y:50)
  }
}
```

the `init()` func is only used when you are creating a new object in code. Which is actually what you are doing in block **3** which goes completely against your question about referencing a sprite from the Scene editor.

You can delete the init() if you want, unless you have plans to add objects via code at another time

you then need to reference the object you added in the Scene editor. In block **3** you are not referencing that object, you are creating a new object.

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

  private var ball: Ball

  override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    if let ball = childNode(withName: "ball") as? Ball {
        self.ball = ball
        ball.moveBall()
    }  
}
```

> Original Answer

You haven't shown us anywhere that the object `initBall` gets called

You'll need to ensure that your subclass file has the proper initializer if you are adding in the Scene Editor

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
```

What I do is either call a setup file from the subclass `required init` or call it from code if it needs a variable for setup

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    setup()
}

func setup() {

    ball = childNode(withName: "ball") as? SKSpriteNode
    ball.size = CGSize(width: 35, height: 35)
}
```

or

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

func setupWith(variable: SomeVariableType) {

    if variable == x {

        //setup based on variable
    }
    else {

        //setup based on variable
    }
}

...in your Scene...

if let ball = childNode(withName: "ball") as? Ball {
    self.ball = ball

    ball.setup(variable: someVarHere)  
}
```

Comment: I was so convinced that `childNode(withName:)` had to be in my custom class that none of your suggestions were making sense. Once I realized that it didn't, things fell into place.

Answer (score 0):

the class Ball is the *blueprint* for a sprite-ball object.. you do not want to have a property *inside of the blueprint for a ball*.. that is like inception for ball sprites :) you want your functions to be taking action on self so

`moveUp() { self.position .... }`

your `initBall` also just needs to be a regular `init`. You are trying to set something literally to itself, like, `let 1 = 1`

Here is essentially what you have written only with cats instead of sprites:

```
class Cat {

  var cat: Cat!

  initCat() {
   cat = Cat()
  }

  func catMeows() {
    print("meow!")
  }
}
```

What you want is:

```
class Cat {

  func meow() {
    print("meow!")
  }
}
```

Also, in your gamescen you need to cast it 'as! Ball' not a spritenode. You are referencing the right object (if you fixed your ball class) just dont have access to the Ball methods because of incorrect cast.

Comment: I get the concept, I think, but what I don't get is how to reference the sprite I've already created in GameScene.sks (or what I believe is referred to as the level editor.) The blueprint above just creates a new cat - it doesn't reference the cat that was created using the level editor.

Comment: @squarehippo10 where are you trying to reference the sprite from? In your `Ball` class, `self` IS THE BALL in your SKS.

Comment: @squarehippo10 Did you set Custom Class property in Scene Editor  to `Ball` type, on your sprite?

Comment: I did set the Custom Class property to `Ball`. I think what you and @Fluidity are saying, is that once I've done that, `self`should refer to the sprite I created in the level editor. But that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: @squarehippo10 it is though. i just noticed you are casting your object as a spritenode, not as ball. see my last sentence in updated answer.